# Concatenate bytes to get char

Tags: java

How would one concatenate two byte primitives to get one char in java? I'm currently trying this:

```
byte a = 0x01;
byte b = 0x02;
char c = (char) (a + b);
```

which gives 0x03. The answer I want is 0x0102.

Is there no simple way to concatenate primitives? I'm surprised there isn't an obvious solution, since it seems like it should be easy. Maybe there is and I just don't see it. :p

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By shifting left 8 bits and adding. Something like,

```
byte a = 0x01;
byte b = 0x02;
char c = (char) ((a << 8) + b);
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(c));
```

Output is

```
102
```

As pointed out in the comments (by [@ChrisMartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402884/chris-martin)) you could bitwise-or (and I'll add you might also `xor`) like

```
char c = (char) ((a << 8) | b);
```

and

```
char c = (char) ((a << 8) ^ b);
```

To all achieve the same result. Since you should [Write Dumb Code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html) I suggest you use whichever you find easiest to understand.

Comment: Might as well bitwise-or instead of adding. `(a << 8) | b`

Answer (score 1):

If you are not opposed to using a 3rd party library, Guava's [Chars.fromBytes](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Chars.html#fromBytes%28byte,%20byte%29) method does exactly this:

```
char c = Chars.fromBytes(0x01, 0x02);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression is `((a << 8) | (b & 0xff))`:

```
    byte a = (byte) 0x81;
    byte b = (byte) 0x82;
    char c = (char) ((a << 8) | (b & 0xff));
```

A byte, when used in an expression, is promoted to an `int` and when this is done, it is sign-extended. The expressions in the other answer only worked when `b <= 127`.

If you add 1 more to that value, as a byte, it will have the value `-128`. (The range of a byte in Java is -128 to 127) so you usually have to mask a byte with `b & 0xff` when you're using it to store unsigned numbers. You don't need to do that with `a` in the above expression since all the high-order bits are shifted out of the resulting 16-bit char.